# What software library is avaliable for RPI camera module?

Tags: camera, image

Where can I find software library to play with camera module?

What is the quality of images?

Is there any page that explains how camera module works?

Does the image processing module use NEON?

Comment: Was your question answered? If so, please mark the answer that solved it as such. We're trying to clean up the site and get it up to par. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Right now there is no python library available for the RPi Camera. However you can use a call statement to call commands from the command line.
For Example, the command to take a still picture is:

```
subprocess.call(["raspistill -o hello], shell=True)
```

You would also need to import subprocess to use call using:

```
import subprocess
```

Just as a side note, You would have to run any script that interfaces with the camera from the command line.

Comment: Thanks. I am looking on code that controls camera. The c code which is part of os that controlscamera

Answer (score 1):

I suppose I should add my own little effort in here: a pure Python library for controlling the camera module called [picamera](http://picamera.readthedocs.org).

Answer (score 0):

There is a work-in-progress library of sorts on Github: https://github.com/recantha/camera-pi

I haven't used it, as I still have to get a camera module of my own, but it might be worth looking at.

Answer (score 0):

Userland provides the toolkit for interactive with PiCam now. The source can be found here and works very well indeed!

https://github.com/raspberrypi/userland/tree/master/host_applications/linux/apps/raspicam

Here are my notes from my install in case it helps anyone-

```
yum -y install cmake

#native compile on PI (example)
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..


#get the source
cd /usr/src
git clone git://github.com/raspberrypi/userland.git
cd userland

#run this command first to set toolchain
sed -i 's/if (DEFINED CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE)/if (NOT DEFINED CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE)/g' makefiles/cmake/arm-linux.cmake

#compile it (use uname -a to get version)
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=3.6.11
make
make install


yum install 'raspberrypi-vc-*'

# NEXT WE NEED TO GET THE PROPER BOOT FILES FOR THIS RELEASE
wget http://larskiesow.de/pyCA/piCA/downloads/pidora-boot-for-camera.tar.gz

tar xf pidora-boot-for-camera.tar.gz

# MAKE SURE TO CP YOUR OLD BOOT/CONFIG.TXT AND REPLACE AFTER THESE COMMANDS BEFORE REBOOTING OR YOU MAY TEMP BRICK YOUR PI

cp -r /boot boot-backup

rm -rf /boot/*

cp -r boot/* /boot/
```

And your all set! View the readme to be see the available commands, etc.